# C# Override CheckedBoxList Display Member

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

Is there a way to set multi-column display member for CheckedListBox without the need to create a new class that merges the properties values together? Something like overriding DisplayMember for example?

I am using C# 4.0 VS 2015

Comment: A multi-column list control with checkboxes is a ListView with View = Details and CheckBoxes = True.  Teaching CheckedListBox the same tricks is not worth anybody's time.

Comment: If you are looking for a real multi-column control, `ListView` or `DataGridView` is what you are looking for. But if you are looking for a way to format display value of the `CheckedListBox` based on multiple properties you can rely on its `Format` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to override `DisplayMember`. Instead, you can handle [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `CheckedListBox`, this way you can provide custom display value for each element.

> The Format event is raised before each visible item in the ListControl
>   is formatted. Handling this event gives you access to the string to be
>   displayed for this list item, through the `Value` property of the
>   [ListControlConvertEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrolconverteventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

The event argument of the event, contains a `ListItem` property which is the object behind the item, so you can mix some properties here and assign the result to `e.Value`.

For example, supposing you are showing a `List<Product>` in your `checkedListBox1`, we can customize the appearance simply this way:

```
private void checkedListBox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    var p = (Product)e.ListItem;
    e.Value = string.Format("Name: {0}, Price: {1}", p.Name, p.Price);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i was looking for this for long time!